# Why do I feel extremely hungry on some days as opposed to others?

Tags: diet

I'm currently trying to keep my calorie limit around 1500 calories a day in order to lose some weight.  I've noticed that on some days I can easily maintain this, even after a tough workout, while on other days I have to eat 500 more calories in order to keep the hunger down.  I know it has nothing to do with diet since I've made it my mission to eat healthy consistently every day.

Height: 5'9

Weight: 222 lbs

TDEE: 2400 Sedentary ; 2700 Moderate Exercise

Comment: Not all calories are created equal. 1500 calories worth of Cheetos will not fill you up as much as 1500 calories of protein.

Comment: Consider your fluid intake - a full belly negates "hunger" and drinking water is generally good at this without providing calories.

Comment: Enough of sleep reduces hunger (you can find research on this topic by googling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use to have a harder time cutting rather than bulking, because eating brown rice, 1/2 pound lean chicken, salmon, spinach,fat free Greek yogurt, oatmeal, and Sweet potatoes is surprisingly filling. The reason why ...

Saturated fat, sugar, etc is a lot of calories.. eating a greasy pack of fries can be a 400 -500 calorie meal due to all the high calorie fat, even though you're only eating a half potato. If you were to eat a baked potato, you'd be full and only have eaten  150-200. Imagine a glass bowl(it's your stomach). Put two tablespoons of oil in it.. this is equal to 200 calories. Now clean it out and put a handful of spinach in it until it's full.. the spinach fills up the entire bowl, but is only 30 calories.. if you were to fill the bowl with oil you'd be eating 3000 calories, and would probably feel sick. You feel full when the bowl is full.. basically eating lean food and drinking water will make you full.. it's actually hard to overreact when you eat clean

Comment: Applying this principle worked for me.  When I needed to drop some weight, I would start dinner with a big green salad and then have smaller portions of the other courses. I still ate most of the same things as before, but didn't need as much of them to feel full. Over time, I naturally stopped overeating and craving junk.  Starting meals with veggies is my winning strategy for weight loss.

Comment: It's a great strategy. I think cutting out as much saturated fat and sugar work for me.. it's really hard to eat too much when everything you eat is not junk food.